# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show any dropdown

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I try to implement AutoCompleteTextView with Custom Adapter, but it doesn't show me suggestion list.

This is snippet of my activity:

```
Member newMember = new Member();
newMember.setMemberID(1);
newMember.setMemberName("TEST 1");
mAllMemberList.add(newMember);
newMember = new Member();
newMember.setMemberID(2);
newMember.setMemberName("TEST 2");
mAllMemberList.add(newMember);

mMemberInputField = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.memberInputField);
mAllMemberListAdapter = new MemberInputListAdapter(this, mAllMemberList);
mMemberInputField.setAdapter(mAllMemberListAdapter);
```

MemberInputListAdapter.java

```
public class MemberInputListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Member> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Member> mMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();

    public GroupMemberInputListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Member>members) {
        super(context, R.layout.all_member_listview_item, members);
        mContext = context;
        mMembers = members;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int rowPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_member_listview_item, parent, false);          
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Member.java

```
public class Member implements Serializable{
    private int memberID;
    private String memberName;

    public int getMemberID() {
        return memberID;
    }
    public void setMemberID(int memberID) {
        this.memberID = memberID;
    }
    public String getMemberName() {
        return memberName;
    }
    public void setMemberName(String memberName) {
        this.memberName = memberName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return memberName;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I miss that my `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't show my anything when I start to type "Tes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom ArrayAdapter should implements the `Filterable` interface.
You can take a look at [this example](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext).